# iOS Most Efficient Way To Match Text

Tags: ios, validation, search

I'm working on an app where I'm validating the users input against a 5000 line list. - i.e. matching the name entered exists in the list.

Whats the most efficient and quickest way to do this - should i convert the text list into a plist then validate by checking through that?

Thanks.

Comment: _Maybe_ a regular expression?

Comment: Put the strings in a set and see if the set contains the text.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `[input isEqualToString:existingString]` for every existing string is going to be very slow.

A quick way to do it would be to maintain your existing entries as keys into a dictionary, storing some value. What the value is doesn't matter, the point is you can try and get a value from the dictionary using the input.

```
if([existingEntriesDictionary objectForKey:input] != nil)
{
    // entry is found!
}
else
{
    // doesn't exist
}
```

If you get something - it exists. If you get nil, it doesn't exist.

Comment: "Very slow" is a relative notion. If you only have 200 strings to test and you're only doing it when a user submits a form, I'm willing to bet that the user will never notice anything. I agree with your answer though, using a dictionary should be a fair bit faster :)

Comment: It's true, everything is relative. My first iOS app used a Scrabble tournament dictionary and I had a similar problem. 267,000 words made it important to do this fast!

Comment: Ooops ok i miscounted. I actually have 5000 lines!
I presume that number would result in the user noticing ?

Comment: In benchmarking, always test. I would guess 5000 words would cause a noticeable delay but on a 5S that may not be true.

Comment: For the record, I used to strcmp() a list of ~10000 strings on an iPhone 3G, and it was sort of acceptable (took ~1 second). Of course iPhones today are a lot faster… You should definitely try a naive approach first and optimize if you need to.

Comment: Hi - thats kind of interesting 10000 took ~1 sec.
I'll give it a go see how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: I feel strcmp() on every string isn't being the best programmer you can be. Efficiency isn't just about not making your user wait but about preserving battery life, developing good habits, understanding your environment etc. - but it's a personal preference thing, if it works for you that's OK.